# Camera.PreviewCallback equivalent in Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop, yuv, android-hardware

Is there any equivalent for Camera.PreviewCallback in Camera2 from API 21,better than mapping to a SurfaceTexture and pulling a Bitmap ? I need to be able to pull preview data off of the camera as YUV?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can start from the Camera2Basic sample code from Google.

You need to add the surface of the `ImageReader` as a target to the preview capture request:

```
//set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface
mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
```

After that, you can retrieve the image in the `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener`:

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            if (image != null) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                Bitmap bitmap = fromByteBuffer(buffer);
                image.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

To get a `Bitmap` from the `ByteBuffer`:

```
Bitmap fromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

Comment: it freezes the Textureview. (mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use the [ImageReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) class.

Create an ImageReader using the format ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 and your desired size (make sure you select a size that's supported by the camera device you're using).

Then use ImageReader.getSurface() for a Surface to provide to CameraDevice.createCaptureSession(), along with your other preview outputs, if any.

Finally, in your repeating capture request, add the ImageReader provided surface as a target before setting it as the repeating request in your capture session.

Comment: @ Eddy Talvala,  When I add target  like mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface()); It freezes the surfaces.

Comment: What error do you get in the logcat? And did you add the surface to your createCaptureSession call?

Comment: Yes set both surfaces for output in createCaptureSession. Logcat doesn't show any Error. It lock straight forward but stuck from last two day.

Comment: logcat :-  Time out while waiting for request to complete. It sends only three requests to ImageReader Callback.

Comment: Are you calling image.close() after being done with each Image? If not, you'll starve the camera for free buffers.

Comment: Thanks, I sorted out the problem. I was not consuming the Image reader on callback. I was just displaying a log to test callback run or not.