# How to capture frame by frame images from Android video recording in real time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, video-processing, video-capture

I want to get realtime frames from video. like camera is open and I am getting frames per seconds.

I have also gone through google example of video capturing app via camera2 API https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video
, But couldn't find any such method/way.

I know this is possible as video broadcasters and apps like snapchat who does realtime video processing must be doing something like this.

Also I require 30 frames/seconds.

Comment: have you got a solution to this question?

Comment: answer added, plz check.

Comment: can you please explain me how to i capture video continuously and get the frame from this video only 7 second and save into Internal Storage not full video please.

Comment: you can save video for 7 seconds and then get frames. Other option for getting realtime frames is this method(in answer), if you need to do some face detection edge detection, this is the place.

Comment: then how to i get real time video frame ? if i press the button before 7 second it's save video. if i pressed after 7 second like video recording 20 second and i pressed the save button then how to save only 7 second video not 20 second video ?? can your please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get frames by using ImageReader for camera2 API. And preview callback for camera1 API.

Here is how to do it with [camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440599/camera-previewcallback-equivalent-in-camera2-api) API.

One can also explore this [library](https://github.com/silvaren/easyrs) for working example with both camera2 and camera1 API.